# Numpy average does not work on map object

Tags: python, numpy, mapping

I have an array that contains strings representing numbers.

```
a = ["101", "102", "103"]
```

I wanted to take the average of this array, so I tried mapping each element into a `float` and then using `np.average`

```
>>> np.average(map(float, a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in average
  File "C:\Users\alonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 380, in average
    avg = a.mean(axis)
  File "C:\Users\alonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 190, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'map' and 'int'
```

If I convert the numbers by iteration it works, but if I have to use iteration this defeats the purpose of map.

```
np.average([float(i) for i in a])

102.0
```

Map returns a map object

```
map(float, a)
<map object at 0x0000022E46035D60>
```

But then, it looks like python doesn't know how to divide map by int.

If I convert map into a list, then it works, it doesn't create a list of maps, but rather evaluates the map value and creates a list of floats

```
list(map(float, a))
[101.0, 102.0, 103.0]
```

However converting map into an array doesn't.

```
np.array(map(float, a))
array(<map object at 0x0000022E2D4A84F0>, dtype=object)


np.average(np.array(map(float, a)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in average
  File "C:\Users\alonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 380, in average
    avg = a.mean(axis)
  File "C:\Users\alonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 190, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'map' and 'int'
>>>
```

Why does this happen? Am I missing something or is an implementation limitation of numpy?

It looks counterintuitive to me that if I map something into floats I have to explicitly convert them into a list before taking the average, shouldn't `np.average` already handle that?

Comment: Numpy array is different from the python list. Try this ```np.average(np.array(a, dtype=np.int32))```

Comment: What's the purpose of map'? You'll have to evaluate it sooner or later..  `numpy` doesn't do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just forget about `map`. It provides poor readability and is rarely useful. List comprehensions and generator expressions have made it obsolete.

As for why it doesn't work: Map returns an iterator object in Python-3. It used to be a list in Python-2, which is why this might have worked in the past. However, numpy generally doesn't handle iterators gracefully. Use `np.fromiter(map(float, a), dtype=float)` or `np.array(list(map(float, a)))`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, map ceases to return a list object, so if you want a new list and not just something to iterate over, you either need `list(map(float, mylist)` or `[float(i) for i in lst]`